# HashRouter URL is updated on click but component not (blocking updates)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've created an app via `create-react-app`. I want to use the `HashRouter` functionality for my app (React Router v4), but it is not working as expected.
Actually I don't know why. I.e. when I click on the `contact` link, then the URL changes to the route `/contacts`, but the related component is not being showed. It still shows the previous loaded component. The links are placed in the `Navigation` component. Here is one example of a `Link`.

```
<Link key={"navigation" + bu.name + "Key"} 
      to="/products" 
      className="nav-link dropdown-item imageLink animated" 
      onClick={(e) => this.handleClickBU(e, bu.bu)}>{bu.name}
</Link>
```

This is my code of `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  HashRouter,
  Route,
  Link,
  Switch
} from "react-router-dom";

<HashRouter>
  <div>
    <Background />
    <div id="wrap">
      <div id="main" className="container clear-top marginBottom50px main">
        <div id="content">
          <Navigation
            key="navBar"
            languagesToShow={this.state.languagesToShow}
            currentLanguage={this.state.currentLanguage}
            onLanguageChange={this.handleLanguageChange.bind(this)}
            onBUChange={this.handleBUChange.bind(this)}
            onIndustryChange={this.handleIndustryChange.bind(this)}
            onCountryChange={this.handleCountryChange.bind(this)}
          />
          <Route
            key={"mainPageRoute"}
            path={"/"}
            exact={true}
            render={(routeProps) => (
              <MainPage
                {...routeProps}
                currentLanguage={this.state.currentLanguage}
                country={this.state.countryObject}
                contacts={this.state.contacts}
                onCountryChange={this.handleCountryChange.bind(this)}
              />
            )}
          />
          <Route
            key={"contactRoute"}
            path={"/contact"}
            exact={true}
            render={(routeProps) => (
              <ContactList
                {...routeProps}
                showCountrySelection={true}
                currentLanguage={this.state.currentLanguage}
                country={this.state.countryObject}
                contacts={this.state.contacts}
                onCountryChange={this.handleCountryChange.bind(this)}
                key={"contactList"}
              />
            )}
          />
          <Route
            key={"productsRoute"}
            path={"/products"}
            exact={true}
            render={(routeProps) => (
              <Products
                {...routeProps}
                ref={this.props.innerRef}
                key="products"
                isLoading={this.state.isLoading}
                country={this.state.countryObject}
                currentLanguage={this.state.currentLanguage}
                currentBU={this.state.currentBU}
                showMainProductGroups={this.state.showMainProductGroups}
                showMainProductGroupDetails={
                  this.state.showMainProductGroupDetails
                }
                showProductGroupDetails={this.state.showProductGroupDetails}
                mainProductGroups={this.state.mainProductGroups}
                onShowMainProductGroupDetailsChange={this.handleShowMainProductGroupDetailsChange.bind(
                  this
                )}
                onShowProductGroupDetailsChange={this.handleShowProductGroupDetailsChange.bind(
                  this
                )}
                onBUChange={this.handleBUChange.bind(this)}
                onCountryChange={this.handleCountryChange.bind(this)}
              />
            )}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</HashRouter>;
```

Can anyone tell me, why the url is updated, but the component not?

**UPDATE**

I already searched a lot and I found [this link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/dealing-with-update-blocking) on the react training site.

I tried different things, but no one did not solve my problem. 
But when I change `HashRouter` to `Router` it works fine!!! Why!?!
Can it be an issue / bug of `HashRouter`?

Comment: Where are your `Link` components? You should wrap your entire app in `HashRouter`, so that the `Link` components will be descendants to it and get the right `history` from context.

Comment: Actually it is all placed inside the `<HashRouter>`. Any other idea?

Comment: Why are you using HashRouter ?

Comment: Don't you need to set the property `component={Component}` on `<Route>` instead of `render`?

Comment: If I use `component={() => <Component {...props}` instead of `render` there is no difference. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. I just got it working that way: [Test](https://codesandbox.io/s/vnowm6q1x7)

Comment: Yeah, normally this works fine, but in this case not. I can't figure out why or a solution to it.

Comment: That's strange.. so you have tried it with: `<Route path="/foo" component={() => <Foo bar="x" />} />`? If yes I sadly don't see the error ATM.

Comment: Yes. That's what I tried.

Comment: Have you thought of the idea that it could be the component and not the actual route? Maybe check if the render method of the child gets called and if yes it's the component.

Comment: I think, it the problem cannot be on the component itself, because when I use the browser navigating arrows for back and forward, then the visual update is also done. It does not work on the click event.